# Let's Take a Vacation!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, geography

I'm planning to take a vacation next year, and I've finally figured out my destination. In celebration of this (as it was a tough choice), I'm making a riddle.

Some of my original options were:

> South Africa, Mexico, Australia, Peru, and New Zealand

There is a common theme to each place I wanted to go, and where I am actually going. Can you figure out where I am going?

> When you visit, you'll need some respect;
>
> Without it you'll find, misguided you'll get.
>
> I'm known for building towers so high;
>
> They're often known to blend with the sky.
>
> But if you're not careful, then you'll never leave;
>
> If they catch you and hold you, you won't want to breathe.
>
> A gem of the world, of I, you are told;
>
> My nature is, a sight to behold.
>
> Its loud like a cannon, while rolling and roaring;
>
> You trip here will be, anything but boring.

As a bonus, can you figure out what activity or activities I based my trip on?

**Hint #1**:

> While you are searching, like a bird I will fly; if you want to find me, then refer to banzai!

**Hint #2**:

> I'm located near the tropic of cancer; but I'm small so look hard, you might find the answer.

**Hint #3**:

> People will come, from both near and far, most of them hodads, who won't try to carve.

All three hints refer to my activity choices, as does part of the riddle.

Comment: Just wanted to comment here because I haven't forgotten about this one; I'm just super stuck haha! It looks like an awesome puzzle! :)

Comment: Updated the riddle after noticing some typos and wrong words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hawaii

When you visit, you'll need some respect;

Without it you'll find, misguided you'll get.

> Tour guides needed to find the best surf spots

I'm known for building towers so high;

They're often known to blend with the sky.

> Volcanic islands with tall mountains

But if you're not careful, then you'll never leave;

If they catch you and hold you, you won't want to breathe.

> Riptides can hold you underwater

A gem of the world, of I, you are told;

My nature is, a sight to behold.

> It's crazy beautiful there

Its loud like a cannon, while rolling and roaring;

> Volcanoes

You trip here will be, anything but boring.

> Tons of cool stuff

Hint #1:

> While you are searching, like a bird I will fly; if you want to find me, then refer to banzai! - **Banzai Pipeline**

Hint #2:

> I'm located near the tropic of cancer; but I'm small so look hard, you might find the answer. - **Small island chain near the tropic of cancer**

Hint #3:

> People will come, from both near and far, most of them hodads, who won't try to carve. - **Most people who visit don't surf**

As a bonus, can you figure out what activity or activities I based my trip on?

> **Surfing** - South Africa, Mexico, Australia, Peru, and New Zealand all have great surfing

I give up if this is wrong, lol. If I knew it didn't have to be a country, I'd have guessed this first.

Comment: Correct, to be exact I'm rot13(tbvat gb Bnuh, zbfgyl sbe gur Onamnv Cvcryvar); though I'll probably be a hodad myself for a few days and just lounge in the sun.

Comment: Also, the hints where you refer to rot13(ibypnabrf), I'm actually referring to rot13(jnirf).

Comment: As rot13(Bnuh vf xabja sbe fbzr bs gur ovttrfg cvcryvar jnirf lrne-ebhaq).

Comment: Right on, if you have time, maybe check out rot13(Jnvzrn Snyyf) while you're there, it is super cool.

Comment: I definitely will! Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

Are you travelling to

> Japan?

When you visit, you'll need some respect;

> The Japanese are known for the utmost respect in their interpersonal relationships.

Without it you'll find, misguided you'll get.

> They don't like it when people are rude.

I'm known for building a tower so high;

> This could be the [Tokyo Skytree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Skytree)

It's often known to blend with the sky.

> It's the tallest extant tower in the world and second tallest structure in the world

But if you're not careful, then you'll never leave;

> ??

If they catch you and hold you, you won't want to breathe.

> ??

A gem of the world, of I, you are told;

> This could be Mount Fuji?

My nature is, a sight to behold.

> There's lots of beautiful natural sights around the mountain

It's loud like a cannon, while rolling and roaring;

> This could be either of [these two waterfalls](http://voyapon.com/fuji-shiraito-waterfalls/)

You trip here will be anything but boring.

> I hope you have fun on your trip!!

The hint

> refers to the Japanese word [banzai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_thousand_years), literally meaning "Ten thousand years" and figuratively translating to a wish for a long life.

Each of the countries you mentioned

> has some beautiful coastline/beaches that you might want to spend some time at!

Comment: El-Guest, I would like to say yes, but; rot13(lbh'er nobhg unys jnl nebhaq gur jbeyq). I'll add another hint! :D

Comment: Though I would ***LOVE*** to go to rot13(Wncna) one day!

Comment: Also, thank you for pointing out rot13(gur Gbxlb Fxlgerr)

Comment: Thanks @PerpetualJ...so what you're saying is I'm close? :P I've heard great things about visiting that country as well, though I personally have never been. I actually learned about it just now, I didn't think they had buildings that tall out there!

Comment: About rot13(svir-gubhfnaq zvyrf njnl)!  I didn't think that either; I always thought it was rot13(Ohew Xunyvsn va Qhonv).

Comment: Doesn't really fit the second hint completely.

Comment: This was interesting research...based on the criteria [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_buildings_and_structures) it appears that they have defined _tower_ to mean _not permanently habitable_. The one you referenced is a permanently habitable building, so it is the world's tallest building/structure but not the world's tallest tower!

Comment: As always, you provide some details that are quite interesting! However, rot13(gbjre pbhyq or flabalzbhf va angher). :D

Comment: OOH very true...I didn't personally realize how pedantic people were about tower definitions either...

Answer (score 1):

I immediately thought of:

> Dubai / UAE

I'm known for building a tower so high;
It's often known to blend with the sky.

> Burj Khalifa

But if you're not careful, then you'll never leave;

> Strict laws

Hint:

> I'm located in the tropic of cancer; but I'm small so look hard, you might find the answer. 
>  **It's close**

Comment: Doesn't fully meet the second hint. There is a key phrase there that needs to be met.

Answer (score 1):

Are you travelling to

> The UAE?

When you visit, you'll need some respect;

> Respect is an important aspect of life in that country.

Without it you'll find, misguided you'll get.

> People don't like it if you're disrespectful there either.

I'm known for building a tower so high;

> The [Burj Khalifa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burj_Khalifa) in Dubai, UAE.

It's often known to blend with the sky.

> It's the world's tallest building.

But if you're not careful, then you'll never leave;

> A reference to their strict laws...?

If they catch you and hold you, you won't want to breathe.

> And their stricter punishments...?

A gem of the world, of I, you are told;

> It's a rich area (gem reference) and very developed.

My nature is, a sight to behold.

> Artificially green areas and built-up fake islands against a backdrop of desert.

It's loud like a cannon, while rolling and roaring;

> [Huh, there's actually a waterfall here too!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadi_Wurayah)

Your trip here will be anything but boring.

> Hope it's fun!!

I still think you based your trip on

> exploring the beaches, and it's located on the Tropic of Cancer and is small as well.

Comment: Loved the reference to rot13(fgevpgre chavfuzragf) made me laugh.

Answer (score 1):

One more try...are you going to

> Nepal?

When you visit, you'll need some respect;

> You'll need to respect the sherpas.

Without it you'll find, misguided you'll get.

> Otherwise, good luck on the mountains.

I'm known for building towers so high;

> "towers" could mean the Himalayas.

They're often known to blend with the sky.

> That, they do -- which mountains would you want to see/climb?

But if you're not careful, then you'll never leave;

> If you're not safe, you could die up there.

If they catch you and hold you, you won't want to breathe.

> It's certainly hard to breathe that high up!

A gem of the world, of I, you are told;

> Mount Everest is one of the natural wonders of the world (citation needed)

My nature is, a sight to behold.

> That it is

It's loud like a cannon, while rolling and roaring;

> [Yet another waterfall!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupse_Falls)

You trip here will be, anything but boring.

> I've always wondered what climbing a mountain would be like!

Comment: El-Guest; this was yet another brilliant answer, but I think you're *thinking* too solid. I'll update with another hint as I don't want to see you bail out now if you've been stuck on it all day! I rot13(qba'g zhpu pner sbe pbyqre jrngure) though rot13(pyvzovat n zbhagnva jbhyq or n avpr npuvrirzrag bar qnl)!

Comment: Haha I'm running all around the world! Sounds great, I'll try to answer before the end of the day!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try again:

> Taiwan

I'm known for building towers so high;

They're often known to blend with the sky.

> Taipei 101

A gem of the world, of I, you are told;

My nature is, a sight to behold.

> A couple Google results to articles similar to: Taiwan - Asia's Hidden Gem and a nature lovers paradise

Its loud like a cannon, while rolling and roaring;

> Several waterfalls

You trip here will be, anything but boring.

> Lots of stuff to do there

HINT 2:

> I'm located near the tropic of cancer; but I'm small so look hard, you might find the answer. - Taiwan is a small country near the tropic of cancer.

Comment: Your new answer meets hint 2 but not hint 1. I'm currently updating with a new hint.

Comment: Is the answer you're looking for a country?

Comment: It is not a country. :)

Comment: I feel like it's cheating to keep submitting answers, but I think I know what it is then, I was limiting my answers to countries. Have fun on your rot13(fhesvat) trip.

Comment: Not cheating, an answer is an answer; if you have more than one you think might be right, then submitting an answer is okay. Especially if you're fleshing it out to explain your reasoning.